# How to manage htaccess inheritance right?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, inheritance

I want to do that:

documentRoot/.htaccess:

```
 - allow access only if a user comes from a specific ip OR if he can authenticate 
 - all others should be rejected
```

documentRoot/somedir/:

```
 - same rules as in documentRoot
```

documentRoot/otherdir/.htaccess:

```
 - 202.111.22.3 should be rejected
 - for the rest: allow access only if a user comes from a specific ip OR if he can authenticate
```

documentRoot/otherdir/csvexport/.htaccess:

```
- allow access to every one
```

My problem is the inheritance from parent htaccess files, i can not get it right, but i hope someone of you is able to solve my issue.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

So you'll have something like this:

> documentRoot/.htaccess

```
Allow From 12.34.56.78
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
```

> documentRoot/otherdir/.htaccess:

```
Deny From 202.111.22.3
Allow From 12.34.56.78
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
```

> documentRoot/otherdir/csvexport/.htaccess:

```
Allow From All
```

`12.34.56.78` being the "specific ip" that you want to allow.